# template v-if="main", not working with return this.$route.path.indexOf('/') === 0 in computed "main"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

works with my other routes like "/dashboard", etc, but is appearing in all routes. I basically want this template to only appear when the url is "/". Have tried it throughout my project and just plum doesn't work. PLease help and thank you!! for any suggestions.

```
<template v-if="main">
  <div id="accordion-nav">
    <div class="accordion-panels">
      <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-panels">
      <a href="/shifts">Shifts <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-panels">
      <a href="/other">Other <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'accordion-nav',
  computed: {
    main: function () {
      return this.$route.path.indexOf('/') === 0
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: This is a single separate component . Where do you use this component?

Comment: '<template>
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar"
    :class="{ isOpen: isOpen }">
     <div class="sidebar-opener"
        @click="toggle">{{openerText}}</div>
     <accordion-nav></accordion-nav>
     <accordion></accordion>
   </div>
</template>'

Comment: @VamsiKrishna sorry for formatting there but i call it in my sidebar.vue component. have tried <accordion-nav v-if="main"> too with no luck either..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup the `v-if` in the sidebar component itself

```
'<template>
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar"
    :class="{ isOpen: isOpen }">
     <div class="sidebar-opener"
        @click="toggle">{{openerText}}</div>
     <accordion-nav v-if="main"></accordion-nav>
     <accordion></accordion>
   </div>
</template>'

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

        }
  },
  computed:{
      main(){
          return this.$route.path === '/'
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

With `this.$route.path` you get a string that equals the path of the current route resolved as absolute path  in any component of your app.
So you can use this to check whether you are in the root route using:

`this.$route.path === '/'`

Here is the [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/94qbxnkn/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `v-if="main"` as a method `v-if="main()"` instead of a computed property

`methods: {
    main: function () {
      return this.$route.path.indexOf('/') === 0
    }`

Methods do such complex updates much better than computed properties. Computed = lazy

Comment: thanks Reiner, this will prob work too, but tried Vamsi's first since the question was asked for component.